# function with loop for urls won't return all of them

Tags: beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, python-3.6

I am working on a project to pull details from state reports on restaurant inspections. Each inspection has its own url. I am able to gather the values into a dictionary, but only return one at a time. In the call to the function, if I don't specify a specific library entry, I get an error: ''list' object has no attribute 'timeout'' If it ask for a specific entry, I get a good return. How can I get them all?

```
# loop through the url list to gather inspection details
detailsLib = {}
def get_inspect_detail(urlList):
    html = urlopen(urlList)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')
    details = soup.find_all('font', {'face': 'verdana'})[10:]
    result = []
    for detail in details:
        siteName = details[0].text
        licNum = details[2].text
        siteRank = details[4].text

        detailsLib = {
            'Restaurant': siteName,
            'License': licNum,
            'Rank': siteRank,
        }
        result.append(detailsLib)

    return result

get_inspect_detail(urlList[21])
```

So I can get the 21st restaurant on the list, repeating 36 times, but not all of them.
Another question for another day is where to do the clean-up. The details will need some regex work but I'm unsure whether to do that inside the function (one at a time), or outside the function by calling all values from a specific key in the library.

Answer (score 0):

Call `get_inspect_detail()` once per item in `urlList`, and save all the results.

```
all_results = []
for url in urlList:
    details = get_inspect_detail(url)
    all_results.extend(details)
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I can understand your approach with this, but it still doesn't seem to work. If urlList contains just one url, this block of code repeats it about 44 times if you 'print(all_results)', and if urlList has two urls, first one repeats 44 times, followed by repeats of the second one. If urlList has a lot of urls, it just hangs.